# when does freeswitch stop transmitting voice streams to asr engine?

Tags: freeswitch

i'm new to freeswitch.I meet some problems. Does freeswitch recogine the pause then stop transmitting voice streams.Or asr engine recogine the pause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes freeswitch does recognize when audio streaming occurs. This is handled when an audio threshold (noise gate) is met.

After the threshold is met you freeswitch has an **energy level** parameter in its mod_conference config file that you can adjust to define your ideal threshold level.

The intent of this parameter is to distinguish if a user is talking if they are in a noisy area.

Comment: thank u.  freeswicth only transmits audio streaming. Does Speech Recognizer Resource recognize when speaking begines and stops ?